# How to find a map key by value of nested map in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a map with another map as its value in Groovy.

Example:

```
[K1 : [k2:v2]]
```

Now I want find `v2` using `K1` key and have to return `K1`.

I am using `.each` loop but `.each` loop continues to run until the end even if I return `K1` in between.

Also I get the whole map as a return value though I expect only `K1` key.

Comment: Next time please also post your actual code with which you have the problem, not only a textual description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `each` method as its name implies always goes through each and every element, the return value of the closure is ignored and the return value again is the complete map as you observed. This is the defined behavior for `each`.

What you want to use is the `find` method which finds the first entry that conforms to your criterion and then use its key like. Something like:

```
[K1: [k2: 'v2'], K3: [k4: 'v4']].find { it.value.k2 == 'v2' }.key
```

Comment: Aren't you assuming (from this `it.value.k2`) that every map will have a key `k2`? I believe he would need `[K1: [k2: 'v2'], K3: [k4: 'v4']].findResult { k, v -> 'v2' in v.values() ? k : null }`

Comment: Nope, I search for an entry that has key `k2` and value `v2`. If there is no such key, the result is `null` and thus inequal to `v2`.

Comment: Agree, but nowhere in OP's question has he asked that he wanted to search based on `k2`.

Comment: As he didn't post his original try, I cannot know what exactly his intention is. My code snippet is just an example of the usage of `find`. What the exact criterion is that he needs is up to him.

Comment: In that case a more generic solution which covers all would be `[K1: [k2: 'v2'], K3: [k4: 'v4']].find { 'v2' in it.value.values() }.key`. Just another approach. :)

Comment: Actually his question does not make too much sense, because he said he searches for `v2` using `K1` and needs to return `K1`. So I assumed he could have meant he serches for `v2` using `K2` and needs to return `K1`.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this :

```
[K1: [k2: 'v2'], K3: [k4: 'v4']].find {'v2' in it.value.values() }?.key
```